# Process exit state 199 Error code in Protractor config

Tags: node.js, angular, selenium, npm, protractor

Error Description:

```
I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:11:17] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:11:18] E/launcher - unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.38 (9047dbc2c693f044042bbec5c91401c708c7c26a-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#779}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64)
[16:11:18] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
  (Driver info: chromedriver=85.0.4183.38 (9047dbc2c693f044042bbec5c91401c708c7c26a-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#779}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19042 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29
    at _fulfilled (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (D:\endtoendtest\HelloProtractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
[16:11:18] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 199
npm ERR! helloprotractor@1.0.0 test: `protractor protractor.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 199
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the helloprotractor@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\srikanth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-12T10_41_19_020Z-debug.log
```

Config File:

```
xports.config = {
        framework: 'jasmine', //Type of Framework used 
        //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
        directConnect:true, 
        specs: ['tests/**/*[tT]est.ts'], //Name of the Specfile 
        onPrepare() { 
              require('ts-node').register({ 
              project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json') // Relative path of tsconfig.json file 
            });
        } 
}
```

I tried updating the webdriver manager also removed the direct connect and tried with selenium address as well.

Can any one please suggest though there are answers for the same question they did not worked for me

Comment: Can you format the code and use code style to improve readability ?